# Delete a single node passed to a function in a linked list C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I have a function `deleteNode` that receives the head of the list, and the node to be deleted. When I run this, It successfully removes the node, but it also removes everything after it. I believe it has to do with me rebuilding the list, but I can't figure out where my logic is wrong so I could use a little help. Here is the function code:

```
void deleteNode(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
    struct lnode* nextNode = nodeGetNext(node);
    printf("word: \n%s\n",nodeGetWord(nextNode));
    struct lnode* nodeToDelete = node;


    *head = nodeGetNext(nodeToDelete);
    printf("Head word: %s\n",nodeGetWord(*head));
    free(nodeToDelete); 
}
```

Comment: hm, you don't seem to be relinking the node after the one you delete to the one before? am i right?

Comment: Say your list is H->...->P->D->N->..., H is the head, D is the node to delete. You first have to unlink D from P and link P to N. Take care when you have to delete the head or the last node ...

Comment: Post definition of `struct lnode` to allow a more useful answer.

Comment: also just from looking at this and making a couple assumptions, it looks like it removes everything BEFORE the node to delete as you point your head to the node after the one to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing it out... I don't know what your functions do exactly, so this makes some assumptions based on the names, but you can get the idea.

1. you pass in `head` (red 'h')
2. you pass in `node` to delete (blue 'n')
3. you set local `nextNode` to the return of `nodeGetNext(node)` (I assume that's the node after the one to delete, the green 'nn')
4. you set `nodeToDelete` (purple ntd) to `node`

[image]

So your code will point head at `nodeGetNext(nodeToDelete)`. This is actually your unused variable `nextNode`. Then you free `nodeToDelete`.

I'm pretty sure this is not what you wanted to do unless you know that the node to delete is right next to head. I think a more normal algorithm would be:

1. from head search for node to delete
2. set "node to delete"-1 next to "node to delete"+1
3. delete "node to delete"

With speical cases for the Head, or an empty list, etc.

Comment: So something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203979/how-to-free-only-a-single-node-in-a-linked-list-in-c)?

Comment: @MattAltepeter - Good, and yes, either of those answers will work, they are both updating correctly.